How to derive Feffermann-Graham expansion for AdS Vaidya geometries?
Introduction
The Feffermann-Graham expansion for an asymptotically AdS spacetime [0] looks like Poincare AdS but with the flat space replaced by a more general metric i.e.
$$ds^2=\frac{1}{z^2}(g_{\mu \nu}dx^\mu dx^nu+dz^2) \tag{1}$$
An example of an asymptotically AdS geometry is the AdS-Vaidya spacetime described by a null shell of matter or a collapsing black hole in AdS space: at small values of the infalling "time" coordinate $v$, the geometry is that of pure AdS with no black hole and at late "times" the geometry is a static AdS black hole. An Eddington-Finkelstein like metric for AdS$_{d+1}$ Vaidya geometry is [1] (c.f. eqn. $(2.10)$) $$d s^2=\frac{1}{u^2}\left(-f(v, u) d v^2-2 d v d u+d \vec{x}^2\right), \quad f(v, u)=1-g(v)\left(\frac{u}{u_H}\right)^d \tag{2.10}$$ where $g(v)$ is the null time $v$ dependent mass function and $u=u_H$ is the location of the event horizon of the black hole at late times. Note that $u$ is not a null coordinate but a purely radial coordinate since putting $u=1/r$ and then using $v=t+f(r)$ with $\frac{df(r)}{dr}=\frac{r^{d-2}}{r^d-m}$ gives the more well known form of AdS Vaidya metric which is
$$d s^2=-\left(r^2-\frac{m}{r^{d-2}}\right) d t^2+\frac{d r^2}{r^2-\frac{m}{r^{d-2}}}+r^2 \sum_{i=1}^{d-1} d x_i^2 \tag{3}$$
For constant $m$ this reduces to the static AdS planar black-hole solution as expected [2].
Question
The paper [1] discusses putting $(2.10)$ in the form of $(1)$ by doing the following coordinate transformations (See Appendix B eqns. (B.$7$) and (B.$8$))
$$v=t-z\left[1+\frac{(d-1) g(t) z^d}{2 d(d+1) u_H^d}+\cdots\right]\tag{B.7}$$ $$ u=z\left[1-\frac{g(t) z^d}{2 d u_H^d}+\cdots\right]\tag{B.8}$$ so that $(1)$ becomes $$d s^2=\frac{1}{z^2}\left[\left(\eta_{\mu \nu}+\tau_{\mu \nu} z^d+\cdots\right) d x^\mu d x^\nu+d z^2\right] \tag{5}$$ with $$ \tau_{00}=\frac{(d-1) g(t)}{d u_H^d}, \quad \tau_{i i}=\frac{g(t)}{d u_H^d}$$
What is the origin of these weird looking coordinate transformations i.e. how can we naturally derive/guess them for the particular problem in hand, given that the motivation is to reduce the metric $(2.10)$ to a Fefferman-Graham form $(1)$. Also, what are the complete untruncated expressions of the coordinate transformations? Any answer giving a reference discussing these metric transformations are also welcome.
References
[0]. Holographic Reconstruction of Spacetime and Renormalization in the AdS/CFT Correspondence by Sebastian de Haro, Kostas Skenderis, and Sergey N. Solodukhin.
[1]. Linear response of entanglement entropy from holography by Sagar F. Lokhande, Gerben W. J. Oling, Juan F. Pedraza.
[2]. Holographic Evolution of Entanglement Entropy by Javier Abajo-Arrastia, Joao Aparicio, Esperanza Lopez.
